# How to make cells selection linked to a Pivot table dynamic?

Tags: excel, dynamic, pivot-table

I have a Pivot table and a formula with range of cells linked to this Pivot table. If I add a new row to the pivot source data, my Pivot table dynamically recognizes this and adjusts (i.e. adds a new row), **however the linked selection does not** (green selection, see image below; the last two rows were newly added to the Pivot source data).

Is there any way how to make sure that the selection updates with the Pivot? I would like to have the green selection dynamically adjust together with the pivot if possible. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You can change the green reference to a dynamic Named Range

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Fernando for a tip. In the end I have managed to do it a bit differently.

I have replaced the `COUNTA` function in the `OFFSET` with the count of unique values in Row Labels (in my case they are names of companies and each company has one value for each year range 2014-2016, 2017-2019).

I.e. now the `OFFSET` `height` is a result of formula which calculates the count of Row Labels meaning that every time I add a new company to my source pivot data the count of unique company names increases by one and consequently the `AVERAGE` range does too.

How to count unique values can be found [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-in-a-range).